# jquery text selector which is immediate to img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can any one tell me, how i can select and alert text "__user_Name_" which is immediate to img with. i am using j query selector.

```
<div id="side-bar" class="test" style="">
<ul>

<li alt="User options">
<a href="#" name="nav1">
<img alt="USERNAME" src="myprofile.png" style="vertical-align: bottom; border: 0px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);">__user_Name_
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a selector, but you can access it vai

```
var el = $('img').prop('nextSibling')
```

here `el` will be a dom element reference, not a jQuery object.

If you just want to read the text then you can use

```
var text = $('img').text()
```

Comment: Arun, wouldn't the text have to be inside of the img element? The img element is not closed with a close tag, so the text is inside of the a tag, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're wanting is the following, though I'm not sure if I've read your question correctly:

To get the text: `$('a[name="nav1"]').text()`

To set the text: `$('a[name="nav1"]').text("New Text")`

Comment: Thanks, i am using greasemonkey script to return user name on page load. i have written below code : 
var name1=$('#side-bar>ul>li>a').find("img").next().text();
:(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .text() method with on the 'a' selector. Something like:

```
var selected = $('a').text();

alert(selected);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8HZf/)